# Displaying equation number+name

Tags: equations

I am writing a chapter of a book and I would like some help to display the equations along with a name+number instead of just a number. For example, `Eq. 1.11` instead of the default `(1.11)` which appears when using the equation command.

Another question, I would like to make all the equations flushed left and I managed to figure out how to do this for single equations using the `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` command, but somehow this doesn't seem to work for gathered equations. Not all equations are shifted all the way to the left of the page when more than one equation is gathered under one equation number.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Can you provide the community with some foundation to start with? Something that shows what you've done up to this point? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: For the tag problem, you have the `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` commands from `mathtools` (§ 3.2 of the doc, *Controlling tags*. For the alignment problem, the simplest solution would be the `fleqn` option with the document class, and a systematic use of the  `align` or `aligned` environments.

Comment: @Bernard thanks a lot, your tips worked like a charm :D
Before I tried using {align} and it did the job of aligning the gathered equations but then the equation number vanished. The {aligned} environment in equation mode worked perfectly. also, the \newtagform and \usetagform did exactly what I wanted....thanks again!